# How do I control "System create" scrollbar in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

1. I create a plain Frame, there is no scrollbar
2. I load a bitmap into this Frame, the bitmap is too big so that system create scrollbar automatically

I want to control this scrollbar, for example, get its CWnd, and then do CWnd::GetWindowRect(myRect), finally, re-paint it.

If this scrollbar is made by me, I know how to get its CWnd, but it is made by system, 
I don't know how to do.

Is it possible to control "system create" scrollbar" ??
thanks!

Comment: The scrollbar is not a separate window, it's part of the window it's in, in the same way a border or a caption is. When you say you want to "control" it, what exactly do you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want re-paint the scrollbar, so I had to know the position of this system-create scrollbar, including the thumb position. So, I want to get its CWnd, and then CWnd::GetWindowRect(myRect), finally, re-paint it.

Comment: If you want to paint the non-client area of your window, including the scrollbar, handle `WM_NCPAINT` message. `GetScrollBarInfo` gives you detailed information about the scrollbar's geometry.

Comment: See also [Flat scroll bars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775429.aspx). These allow you to customize the appearance of the scrollbar to some extent, without having to completely take over painting one from scratch.

Comment: Thank you! the problem is solved, I use this code: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14724/Replace-a-Window-s-Internal-Scrollbar-with-a-custo